# Finding records in the place of origin of an immigrant to Canada & USA from Poland?

Tags: birth-records, military-records, poland

I need research strategies to find birth and early family records of Teodor Pawlowicz born Feb 26,1890 Dzikow, Poland. I believe the village is actually Stary Dzikow.

He emigrated to Canada Quebec May22, 1913 on SS Vaderland. A note says he was from Galicia and was Ruthenian. [His name was later changed to Fred Paulis in U.S.A.]

I was told to remember he was Ukrainian 'White' as in anti- Bolshevik. I remember a tattoo on his R forearm which leads me to believe he had military service which has caused further frustration for lack of family records.

The complex nature of the area in southeast Poland or Galicia has lead to hours upon hours of dead-end search.  I have a reasonable knowledge of the complex times esp in this border area but labyrinths abound.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! I have rearranged some of the information in your question to make it easier for people to read. Your question could be improved if you told us what records you already have on hand.  You say you've searched for hours with no results but you don't say how you searched or where. While you're waiting for answers, try searching the site for other records tagged [tag:poland].

Comment: Thank you for constructive edit  and advice-- another 16 hr day trying to get diefinitive record of Teodore birth in Poland or record of parents/siblings. Nothing in family tree re his pre Canadian/U.S arrival. Having trouble or invisibility searching Austrian-Poland civil registries in archives,of SouthEast equivalent of county seat,parish etc.for birth, baptismal or possible military record.Galicia,Roman Catholic and Grecco Catholic churches as well.  so ...

Comment: It's generally best to search the US/Canada side first for clues.

Comment: Have done so quite thoroughly. He showed nothing of immediate family on any U.S. records and no records in gap between arrival in Canada 1913 and arrival in U.S. 1915. Perhaps no family references to protect them from  repercussions if he left to avoid conscription on 'wrong' side?

Comment: Your question could be improved by telling us briefly what you've already searched and what sources you have on hand.  Otherwise people may attempt lookups to find records for you which you already have.

Comment: Tryg to access Austrio-Pnd rcrd in Austro [Galician] cvl registrar 1784-1918 - flm # 844922     fiche # 6000369-6000383    bk #9438E5s. pre1913 info =  Teodor Pawlowicz, dob Feb 26-1890  Dzikow,Poland psngr list of arvl in Quebec- May 22-1913 on SS Vaderland - other records all after 1915 with name change to Fred Paulis-not Naturalized until 1943-  Discovered message Pawlowicz  board by chance and read all entries - looks promising. There is some time element concern as his last living child [my mother] is 85 yrs and this endeavor inspired by her. I do appreciate your attention and tutorial.

Comment: You can use the edit link under your question at any time to add more information to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the [Słownik geograficzny Królestwa Polskiego i innych krajów słowiańskich](http://dir.icm.edu.pl/Slownik_geograficzny/Tom_II/294) (Geographic Dictionary of the Kingdom of Poland and Other Slavic Countries) and found an entry for Dzików. There are two towns listed and it appears that the [second one](http://dir.icm.edu.pl/Slownik_geograficzny/Tom_II/295) might be yours as it lists Dzików nowy and Dzików stary. It also mentions that there were both Polish Catholics and Orthodox Christians in the town. Dzików was in the [powiat cieszanowski](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powiat_cieszanowski) in the Voivodeship of Lwów.

It turns out that the records for Dzików stary can be found in Syg 1665 of [Księgi metrykalne parafii wyznania rzymskokatolickiego z archidiecezji lwowskiej, 1604-1945](http://www.agad.gov.pl/inwentarze/KLwo301new.xml) (The AGAD archives of Roman Catholic birth, marriage and death records of the Archdiocese of Lwow from 1605 to 1945). While these are the Catholic records it would also have birth records for children of mixed marriages if the the parent of the same sex was Catholic and marriage records if the bride was Catholic.

If you look at the records for Lubaczów, you may find something there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention the village of Dzików was in Galicia, this means it was in the Austro-Hungarian part of Poland which today is south Poland and western Ukraine.

An OpenStreetMap Nominatim search reveals a lot of places called Dzików, the majority of them are excluded as they were part of Germany or Kingdom Congress (Russian Empire) prior to 1914. Several of them could potentially be yours :

- [Stary Dzików](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/31895225) in the subcarpathian region. This village is the "old" Dzików probably build before the "new" Dzików which is directly east. Before the "new" Dzików was built the old was probably simply refered to as "Dzików" (however I have absolutely no idea clue when the new village was built).
- [Dzików](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1165191003#map=13/50.6055/21.7303) village near Tarnobrzeg in the subcarpathian region
- [Dykiv](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/337517493#map=9/50.7834/26.2463) (ukrainian language equivalent of Dzików) village in the region of Rivne, western Ukraine (before 1939 in Poland, before 1918 in Galicia).

Other villages missing from OpenStreetMap and/or destroyed during either World War shouldn't be excluded.